# How to convert bool to string & change values by condition in aggregation pipeline - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have a collection with records ,  Need to convert boolean values of a column to string :

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    passed_phd: true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    passed_phd: true,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    passed_phd: false,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    passed_phd: false,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

how to change boolean value of the records to string.

value that has true(boolean) in passed_phd should be converted  to "yes"(string)

value that has  false(boolean) in passed_phd should be converted  to "no"(string)

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    passed_phd: "yes",
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    passed_phd: "yes",
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    passed_phd: "no",
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    passed_phd: "no",
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

mongodb version 4.0

**Tried this :**

```
{passed_phd : [{'passed_phd':true},{$set:{'passed_phd':"yes"}] }
```

**Error :**

```
Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.
```

Comment: You have to use the `$project` or `addFields` [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html) stage and use the `$cond` or `$switch` operator to convert the value. Also, please post the aggregation query you have tried so far.

Comment: tried this `{passed_phd : [{'passed_phd':true},{$set:{'passed_phd':"yes"}] }`  in aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html) to convert to strings & conditional operator to change field values, try adding below stage to your aggregation pipeline :

```
{
    $addFields: {
      passed_phd: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  "$passed_phd",
                  true
                ]
              },
              then: "yes"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  "$passed_phd",
                  false
                ]
              },
              then: "no"
            },

          ],
          default: {
            $toString: "$passed_phd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1mwxcqi7FH7)

You no need to use `$switch` if field exists & there could be only two values for `passed_phd` field, So just use `$cond` operator :

```
{
    $addFields: {
      passed_phd: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$passed_phd",
              true
            ]
          },
          "yes",
          "no"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gaSaFJN_vo8)

Comment: changing of field values ?  from true to yes and false to no

Comment: @vebey74412 : Do you happen to have anyother value in `passed_phd` field apart from `true or false` ? Or can there be any docs where no `passed_phd` field ?

Comment: only true and false are there , every column has either true or false